# Display images from tree list in Sitecore

Tags: xslt, sitecore

In Sitecore, I have a tree list for the user to select certain images. I would like to use the presentation api to display the images that the user selects. While looking through the Presentation Component XSL reference guide, I found this code:

```
        <xsl:variable name="slideShow" select="/*/item[@key='content']/item[@key='home']/item[@key='Foundation']/item[@key='Landing Pages']/item[@key='Legends Trail Ride']" />

        <xsl:variable name="mediaid" select="sc:fld('Slide Show',$slideShow,'mediaid')" />
        <xsl:if test="$mediaid">
          <xsl:variable name="mediaitem" select="sc:item($mediaid,$slideShow)" />
          <xsl:if test="$mediaitem">
            <a href="{concat('/',sc:GetMediaUrl ($mediaitem))}">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="sc:fld ('title',$mediaitem)">
                  <sc:text field="title" select="$mediaitem" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$mediaitem/@name" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </a>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
```

The page will display so technically there isn't anything wrong with the code but the image still aren't showing. Is this code going in the right direction or is there an alternative way to display images from a tree list?

Comment: That's an awfully long slideshow select statement :( Why are you not just using current item (.)?

Comment: To debug, try adding <xsl:value-of select="$mediaid" /> after setting the variable. Do the same with the mediaitem variable. Could even do the same for slideShow.
It might just be that it doesn't find anything because of typo's or whatever other reason.

Comment: jammykam, could you explain in a little more depth what you mean?

Comment: @jammykam probably means that if your slideShow is the current Sitecore item, you might as well use <xsl:variable name="slideShow" select="." /> as selector.
Have you made sure the code hits the <xsl:choose>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is using the 'web' database, make sure you have published all of your media items or they won't display.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, that's not the problem.

Comment: Try simplifying your code.  Write out some static text to be 100% sure the control is rendering.  Then step it up and write out the Item Ids of the images, etc.  There may be something on a lower level that is tripping up your code.

Answer (score 0):

A typical scenario for your case would be to check if all templates and subtemplates of the specific items on which those images are attached are published. If this is done check your media library folders and media items in those folders. You have to make sure the folder in which you added the images is also published. What you can do to verify the above after you have published is login to the 'desktop' mode of Sitecore and change the database (bottom right corner) to 'web'. Then find all of the described items and see if everything is really published. Most of the times you will encounter issues like this it will actually be publishing.